# SQL mass insert based on existing values in a table?

Tags: mysql, database, insert

Say I have the following table:

**table1**

```
---------------------
|  key   |   value  |
---------------------
---------------------
|   0    |   val0   |
---------------------
|   1    |   val1   |
---------------------
|   2    |   blah   |
---------------------
```

Where key is an integer primary key, and value is a varchar.

Now, I want to create a duplicate row for each existing row in the table with a new key.  The value of each new row will be equal to the value of an existing row, but with a prefix in front of it (using [CONCAT](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-concat-function.htm)).  However, I only want to run this insert if the value has the substring `val` in it.

So the final table should look like this:

```
---------------------
|  key   |   value  |
---------------------
---------------------
|   0    |   val0   |
---------------------
|   1    |   val1   |
---------------------
|   2    |   blah   |
---------------------
|   10   | pre_val0 |
---------------------
|   11   | pre_val1 |
---------------------
```

Is there any way to create an insert statement that could do this sort of thing?  Here's some pseudo code (that doesn't work) to give a better idea of what I'm trying to accomplish.

```
insert into table1 (key, value) values (key + 10, CONCAT('pre_', value)) 
where value like '%val%';
```

Is there any way to achieve this sort of thing?

Comment: For all intents and purposes this is my real case with simplified table column names and values, and less rows.  My real case would look the same but much larger and longer names.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your task could easily produce `key` collision. If `key` is PK then you get error when trying to insert the same value twice. Anyway:

```
CREATE TABLE table1(`key` INT PRIMARY KEY, `value` VARCHAR(100));

INSERT INTO table1(`key`, `value`)
SELECT  0,'val0' 
UNION ALL SELECT   1 , 'val1'   
UNION ALL SELECT   2 , 'blah';


INSERT INTO table1(`key`, `value`)
SELECT `key` + 10, CONCAT('pre_', `value`)
FROM table1
where `value` like '%val%';
```

<kbd>**[`SqlFiddleDemo`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8d9453/1/0)**</kbd>

Output:

```
╔══════╦══════════╗
║ key  ║  value   ║
╠══════╬══════════╣
║   0  ║ val0     ║
║   1  ║ val1     ║
║   2  ║ blah     ║
║  10  ║ pre_val0 ║
║  11  ║ pre_val1 ║
╚══════╩══════════╝
```

I suggest to not add 10 to `key` but use `AUTOINCREMENT` instead.